# Typescript- Uncaught Reference: require is not defined when using export default

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to correctly create a default export in typescript? A default export resolves to `const ExampleModule_1 = __importDefault(require("./ExampleModule"));` in the code that's importing it.

Subsequently the console will log `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Answers that say to use RequireJS don't solve the issue. When I include the script I get:
`require.js:5  Uncaught Error: Module name "ExampleModule" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Non-default exports which don't rely on "require" are working fine.